# ls'ing through an entire directory tree to produce one pipeable list of files

Tags: ls, directory

This might have been answered already. But I wasn't able to find it.

I have:

```
directory
directory/subdirectory/subdirectoryofsubdirectory
directory/sub-subdirectory/subdirectoryofsub-subdirectory/subdirectoryofsubdirectoryofsub-subdirectory
directory/sub-sub-subdirectory
directory/sub-sub-sub-subdirectory
```

each directory and subdirectory contains files. I want to list them all, pipe the list to cat, and cat the list to a text file. Can this be done with a 'one liner'? If so, please provide it. Or does it require a script and, if so, what commands/structures will I need to write the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that your best bet is the `find` command.  If you want just the files and not the directories in your list, something like this:

```
find directory/ -type f -print > textfile
```

The find command will recursively list the files. (If you want the directories listed too, remove the `-type f`).  The `> textfile` redirects stdout to a file named textfile with no need for cat.

`find` is a powerful tool with many options.  See `man find` if you find that you need to tweak the output slightly.

**UPDATE** (thanks [gvkv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/160/gvkv)):

If you want to put the *contents* of the files into a single text file, then one way to do it is:

```
find Documents/ -type f -exec cat {} + > textfile
```

Comment: If you'd like to print only the filename, not the full path, use `-printf '%f\n'` instead of `-print`.

Comment: Does the OP want a list of files in the text file or the contents of the files in the text file?  I interpreted the question as the latter.

Comment: @gvkv good point.  I will update my answer.

Comment: use xargs instead of -exec for better process efficiency.

Comment: @jmtd: According to the man page, the `+` rather than `\;` should be roughly the same as using xargs.

Comment: It was never about contents, only filenames. That said, thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 3):

`find` is the generic way, as [Steven D's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/lsing-through-an-entire-directory-tree-to-produce-one-pipeable-list-of-files/2288#2288) explains. If your shell supports it, `**` can be used to match any number of subdirectories (on bash it's the same as `*` and only matches one by default, but see Dennis' comment), so you can just do:

```
cat **/*
```

Comment: Dude, where do you *learn* this stuff?  Awesome!

Comment: learn this? micheal writes it down here first, then hacks into YOUR ( and everyone elses ) pc and implements the behaviour there. +1 @micheal

Comment: Bash 4 will do that if you `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: @gvkv: Probably by Reading the Friendly Manual :)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek I've never ventured outside of bash in my 8 years on Linux. I've heard good things about zsh, though.

Comment: @ixt We seem to have a lot of zsh users here, generic shell questions tend to get zsh answers

Comment: @MichaelMrozek ...or **bash** answers for that matter (in case someone asks "And what makes bash more generic than zsh?") I'm sure I'm guilty of a few such.

Comment: this probably implodes in `bash` or `zsh` unless the directory tree is a small one due to ARG_MAX. The `zargs` function in `zsh` will handle it robustly though.